# vbscript list logged on users to terminal server

Tags: vbscript

Try to list the logged on users to a windows terminal server in a workgroup via vbscript.

I have the below but it does not seem to return the logged on users?

```
strComputer = "."  

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
              & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
              & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colSessions = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 10") 

If colSessions.Count = 0 Then 
   Wscript.Echo "No interactive users found" 
Else 
   WScript.Echo "RDP Sessions:"
   For Each objSession in colSessions 

     Set colList = objWMI.ExecQuery("Associators of " _ 
         & "{Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" & objSession.LogonId & "} " _ 
         & "Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" ) 
     For Each objItem in colList 
       WScript.Echo "Username: " & objItem.Name & " FullName: " & objItem.FullName 
     Next 
   Next 
End If
```

Comment: Worked when I tested it for local interactive logons (`LogonType = 2`). Are you positive there are RDP users logged into the host where you're running this script?

Comment: Yeah - I have 2 users logged in and it does not find any. Tried using 10 & 2.

Comment: Do you get "no intereactive users found" or are just no sessions listed? Have you tried listing all logon sessions indiscriminate of logon type?

Comment: I get: RDP Session message then an error: Line: 19 Char: 6, if I remove the where from LogonType I get System, Network Service, Local Server then the same error.

Comment: Your script works fine in Terminal Server 2003, except that i am the only logged on user using RDP, but it shows my logon 4 times. With Server 2008 R2 Ent, it shows correctly # and name of rdp sessions, no errors.

Comment: What is the error? Also, check the output of `TypeName(colList)`.

Comment: Error is: Error: 0x80041002 Code: 80041002 Source: null

Comment: We are using the OS: Windows 2008 R2 Ent

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to check owners of explorer.exe process.
This will list you all users having open session on server.

```
strComputer = "."

Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
   "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & _
   "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where name = 'explorer.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcesses

    who = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser)

    Wscript.Echo "Process " _
            & objProcess.Name & " is owned by " _ 
            & strNameOfUser & "."
 
Next
```

Example of result:

```
D:\TEMP>cscript get_explorer_owner.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Process explorer.exe is owned by john.
Process explorer.exe is owned by peter.
Process explorer.exe is owned by bob.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run it as Administrator!
run CMD as administrator and run the command CSCRIPT